# is it possible to have cross line within bar chart in chartjs like the below image

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

[image: chartjs cross lines]

I see we can change the color but is it really possible to have colored lines like this

https://codepen.io/diasraphael/pen/mdXzdqr

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart").getContext("2d");

var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Candidate A Votes',
      backgroundColor: "#000080",
      data: [90,0,0]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate B Votes2',
      backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
      data: [0,70,0]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate C  Votes3',
      backgroundColor: "#add8e6",
      data: [0,0,45]
    }]
  },

  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top',
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#000080",
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as described [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/general/colors.html#patterns-and-gradients) you can use a [canvas pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern).

To make it a bit easyer you can use an external lib that draws the pattern you want as the background:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: pattern.draw('diagonal-right-left', '#1f77b4')
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/patternomaly@1.3.2/dist/patternomaly.js"></script>
</body>
```